# Creating a PDF file tracker as Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file which is supposed to keep track of the opened PDF files on my system.As soon as someone opens the PDF file,the name of the file as well as time of access is recorded in a log file.
Here is code of my batch file:

```
@echo off
echo FILE ACCESSED %1 >> I:\Batch\log.txt
echo TIME OF ACCESS %TIME% >> I:\Batch\log.txt
"C:\Program Files\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe" %1
EXIT
```

I have also set up this batch file as the default application fr the PDF files to open with.
Now,the problem is,as soon as I open any PDF file,many cmd windows start opening  and closing unendingly. Please suggest some remedy.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
copy %1 %1.tmp
echo FILE ACCESSED %1 >> I:\Batch\log.txt
echo TIME OF ACCESS %TIME% >> I:\Batch\log.txt
"C:\Program Files\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe" %1.tmp
del %1.tmp
EXIT
```