# Batch File to Open Multiple PDFs | Only Opening 1 at a Time

Tags: batch-file, pdf

I recently "discovered" batch files - and have made a few successful ones to help open tedious amounts of files. However, this morning when trying to make on to open 45 pdfs at the same time it wouldn't work.

I used the instructions from [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/Acrobat/Open-multiple-files-at-once/td-p/8727534) (under Kenp94's answer, and picture below). However, it just opens one at a time and waits until I close the opened pdf before opening the next. I would like to open them all at the same time.

My file looks like this: and is saved in .bat format.

[image: OPENALLPDFSs.bat]

How do I go about getting my files to open all at the same time.

---

That said, I have checked [Opening multiple PDF documents using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695603/opening-multiple-pdf-documents-using-batch-file) and [Creating a PDF file tracker as Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525436/creating-a-pdf-file-tracker-as-batch-file) and I feel my approach is different enough that is warrants a separate question as opposed to gleaning the answer from there - or perhaps I simply don't understand Batch files well enough...

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `For %%I In (*.pdf)Do Start "" "%%I"`.

Comment: @Compo that worked! Thanks - if you want to make that an answer I can approve it for ya!

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code, copy the text into your question and format it properly!

Comment: @aschipfl, I'm not going to that here - as this question has been answered below. But what is the rationale for your request - so I can better format questions in the future.

Comment: So potential answerers can simply copy the code and experiment with it. Otherwise they have to bother to retype it, which may reduce the probability to receive helpful answers or answers at all...

Comment: @aschipfl, great insight. I will be sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@For %%I In (*.pdf)Do @Start "" "%%I"
```

This however suffers from a potential issue, in that `*.pdf` matches all extensions which begin with `.pdf`.

To properly limit it to only `.pdf` extensions, you could use the internal `Dir` command together with [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr):

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%I In ('Dir /B/A-D "*.pdf" 2^>NUL^|FindStr ILE ".pdf"')Do @Start "" "%%I"
```

Alternatively, you could use `Where.exe`:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%I In ('Where .:*.pdf" 2^>NUL')Do @Start "" "%%I"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/WAIT` switch to the `start` command

```
for %%v in (*.pdf) do start "" /WAIT "%%v"
```